# Directshow how to control Area of Interest

Tags: c++, directshow, offset, area

I'm using c++ with directshow to capture multiple images from the camera, much like how opencv camcapture does.

And the camera I'm using has a AoI control where I can move the offset of x and y to move the camera view. I try searching the web, but I couldn't find anything.

Is there a way to control those values using directshow? Cause there seems to be way to change the values of gain and what not, but there's no mention about the AoI control

Answer (score 0):

This totally depends on the source directshow filer that you got with your camera and you should check it's documentation / view it's property page with graph edit.

If it's a standard filter you are using, try to switch to the one you got with your hardware, since the lack of results probably means there is no support for this option in the standard src filter.